# How does platypus "guess" bold and italic styles?

Tags: python, reportlab, platypus

Here's my code. My first function is based on the `/Lib/site-packages/reportlab/lib/styles.py` source code, to create an array of `style`:

```
def create_styles(p_tuples):
    retour = StyleSheet1()
    parent = None
    for p_name, font_name, font in p_tuples:
        # (!) change path if Linux:
        ttf_file = "C:/Windows/Fonts/{}.ttf".format(font)
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(font_name, ttf_file))
        if parent is None:
            p = ParagraphStyle(name=p_name,
                               fontName=font_name,
                               fontSize=10,
                               leading=12)
            retour.add(p)
            parent = p
        else:
            retour.add(ParagraphStyle(name=p_name,
                                      parent=parent,
                                      fontName=font_name,
                                      fontSize=10,
                                      leading=12))
    return retour
```

Then I build my own array with my installed fonts:

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    # this is a response for Django, but the question is about styles
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf; charset=utf-8')
    # ! Hint : no filename -> the browser extracts it from the URL!
    #   -> create URLs like http://pdfreportlab.com/extract/myfilename.pdf
    #   this is the way to go to have 100% working UTF-8 filenames!
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=""'

    my_styles = self.create_styles([
        ('ms-regular', 'montserrat-regular',
         'Montserrat-Regular'),
        ('ms-black', 'montserrat-black',
         'Montserrat-Black'),
        ('ms-black-italic', 'montserrat-black-italic',
         'Montserrat-BlackItalic'),
        ('ms-bold', 'montserrat-bold',
         'Montserrat-Bold'),
        ('ms-bold-italic', 'montserrat-bold-italic',
         'Montserrat-BoldItalic'),
    ])
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response)
    elements = []
    c = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=A4, )
    for idx in my_styles.byName:
        p = Paragraph("Hello World <i>italic</i> <b>bold</b>",
                      style=my_styles[idx])
        width, height = p.wrapOn(c, A4[0], A4[1])
        elements.append(p)
    doc.build(elements)
    return response
```

Everything is working except the (very annoying) fact that the `<i></i>` and `<b></b>` tags are ignored! It only uses the current font in the style.

How could you modify my code so that it takes in account the tags and I finally get styles with the tags in the text itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a font family if you want Platypus to auto-select fonts - you're creating a different style for every font variant so of course the `<i>` and `<b>` tags have no effect - it doesn't know what fonts to use for them as the passed style references a single font.

Here's how to build a style using a font family:

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFont, registerFontFamily
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont


def create_paragraph_style(name, font_name, **kwargs):
    ttf_path = "C:/Windows/Fonts/{}.ttf"
    family_args = {}  # store arguments for the font family creation
    for font_type in ("normal", "bold", "italic", "boldItalic"):  # recognized font variants
        if font_type in kwargs:  # if this type was passed...
            font_variant = "{}-{}".format(font_name, font_type)  # create font variant name
            registerFont(TTFont(font_variant, ttf_path.format(kwargs[font_type])))
            family_args[font_type] = font_variant  # add it to font family arguments
    registerFontFamily(font_name, **family_args)  # register a font family
    return ParagraphStyle(name=name, fontName=font_name, fontSize=10, leading=12)
```

Then you can create your paragraph style as:

```
pstyle = create_paragraph_style("ms", "montserrat",
                                normal="Montserrat-Regular",
                                bold="Montserrat-Bold",
                                boldItalic="Montserrat-BoldItalic")
```

assuming, of course, that you have TTF files with those names in your fonts directory.

You can then add it to your stylesheet (especially if you want parent inheritance - make sure you add it as an argument to be forwarded to the `ParagraphStyle` creation) or directly use it as:

```
p = Paragraph("Hello World <i>italic</i> <b>bold</b> <b><i>boldItalic</i></b>", style=pstyle)
```

(the standalone italic won't be affected as we didn't define it in the family, tho).

Comment: `("normal", "bold", "italic", "boldItalic"):  # recognized font variants` are hard coded in all systems? It's a de-facto standard?

Comment: @OlivierPons - those are 'hardcoded' arguments for `reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics.registerFontFamily()` function (the signature is: `registerFontFamily(family,normal=None,bold=None,italic=None,boldItalic=None)`) - in the above code it's a shorthand so you don't have to convert/pass names from one argument set to another.

Comment: If I try this hard-coded solution here: http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2010-October/009795.html then it works. I found out that your solution doesn't work because (I guess this is a bug). Here's how I changed your code to make it work: (1) remove `normal` from your loop and (2) add this line just before your loop: `registerFont(TTFont(font_family, ttf_path.format(kwargs['normal'])))` (infering that '`normal`' is always passed in kwargs). 3 hours for this.

Comment: What I found is that if you register the font '`Montserrat-normal`' with the ttf file, then it can't find the montserrat and you get this error: `Can't map determine family/bold/italic for montserrat`. If you register *both* '`Montserrat`' and '`Montserrat-normal`' with the same ttf file then you get only italic text (!!). So the solution is to register only '`Montserrat`' once, without the word '`normal`'. Pretty sure this is a bug. PS: your Python level is excellent!

Comment: When I said "I guess this is a bug" it's about platypus and reportlab, not your code (which is excellent IMHO). Each time I do step by step debug in reportlab, my eyes are burning, I need eye drops!